# Запуск кода через промежуток времени (каждую минуту на N-ной секунде)

Tags: python, datetime, scheduler

Как мы все знаем есть функция `time.sleep(10)` - исполнять код каждые 10 секунд. А как сделать так, чтобы эти 10 секунд были не в любое время, как например в **19** часов **14** минут **3** секунды, а затем **13** секунд, **23**.... А чтобы старт был с каждой 10 секунды по времени комьютера?

Comment: `time.sleep(10)` не исполняет код каждые десять секунд, а останавливает процесс на десять секунд. Чтобы ваш скрипт запускался каждые десять секунд с какого-то времени, вам стоит использовать планировщик задач.

Comment: да, останавливает на 10 секунд, опечатка. В любом случае нужно чтобы десять секунд были привязаны к времени

Comment: Посмотрите модуль https://github.com/dbader/schedule там много всяких вариантов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime.now().second` дает текущую секунду. Если из нужной вам секунды вычесть текущую, можно узнать, сколько секунд осталось ждать.

`Timer(секунды, функция).start()` откладывает вызов функции на указанное время.

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

def on_10th_second():
    print('yo-ho-ho', datetime.now())


def shedule(func, nth_sec):
    now_sec = datetime.now().second
    wait = (60 + nth_sec - now_sec) % 60
    # На  7-й секунде: (60 + 10 - 7) % 60 → 3 (осталось 3 сек до 10-й)
    # На 17-й секунде: (60 + 10 - 17) % 60 → 53

    Timer(wait, func).start()
    Timer(wait + 1, lambda: shedule(func, nth_sec)).start()

shedule(on_10th_second, 10)

print('ok') # В отличие от sleep, синхронный код ниже Timer() продолжает выполняться.
```

А время измеряется на каждой итерации, чтобы задержка между вызовами не накапливалась, вызовы происходили каждый раз примерно на N-й секунде.